# Why javac requires .java extension and java doesn't require .class extension

Tags: java

Why javac looks for .java extensions in filenames.
While java doesn't look for .class in its argument?  And goes to the .class file by itself automatically?
Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Because `javac` compiles Java (`.java`) files into Classes (`.class`) files and `java` executes the generated Classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no automatic adding of `.class`: you just run `java` specifying *which class to use as main.* The details of classloading and classpath are on a different level of abstraction: it is possible that there's no `.class` file, or e.g. it's in a JAR.

If you look closer, by the way, you'll find that `java` does not ask you for a path: there are no slashes (or, worse yet, backslashes) in the parameters, only the proper dots separating package names. So it's never a "file."

`javac`, on the other hand, does indeed work with files, hence you need to specify those.

Comment: Yeah. just now observed that java doesn't look for file paths.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a very sound reasoning behind this decision except for the fact that `.java` files are created by the programmer whereas `.class` files are compiler generated. If this question is meant to be purely for educational purposes, the answer "just because that's how it was meant to be" should be pretty good. :)